# C++ terminology disambiguation

Tags: c++

I've seen *qualified* used in the context cv-qualifiers:

> unqualified types can be implicitly converted to const

But I've also seen *qualified* used to mean any nested type:

> MyClass::MyNestedType x;

---

### What are other homonymic terms from the language standard?

Comment: LOL Just noted 'What are some other confusing C++ terms?'. Voting to close as non-constructive :)

Comment: Confusing to who? To you? We'll need to know more about you first.

Comment: @sehe: I'm all on board for "confusing keywords" (hello `static`), but I think the OP specifically wants "terminology" from the language standard.

Comment: @sehe: A vote to close means 'this question should not be answered as is.'

Comment: @aschepler: I know. We can discuss my conflicting and ambiguous nature on meta :) Or in chat. Sometimes I just like to have fun too. I realize though that the question isn't a very good fit for the SO Q/A format

Comment: I updated the question to better please those with poor sight or interpretation. For reference: **homonymic** - of or related to or being homonyms; **homonym** - words that share the same spelling and the same pronunciation but have different meanings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an addressing of the two meanings of qualification, see below...

#### Well, after seeing the real intended question here goes:

- const, mutable (for functions)
- delete

  - for destruction+freeing dynamically allocated objects *or*
  - for prohibiting auto-generated special class members)
- auto

  - formerly declspec for stack/static variables;
  - in c++11 the 'inferred type' specifier
- virtual

  - for virtual member functions *or*
  - for virtual base classes
- using

  - for defining a namespace alias (sic)
  - for importing a namespace
  - for importing a qualified name into the current namespace

    - note that this does *NOT* mean that the imported name is going to be used; it just means that the compiler will be aware of the imported declaration when *starting* overload resolution. This may result in SFINAE kicking in and selecting a whole different overload/specialization from yet another namespace. **Confusing**!
  - for importing a name from a base class into the derived class (to prevent false name hiding)

Syntax nits:

- `&` for addressof or for `reference type` (debatable - not very confusing)
- `[]` for array indexing or for lambda declaration
- `>>` for right-shift or for closing a nested template definition

  ```
  pop-quiz: what is this: 

      template <size_t> struct X {};
      std::vector<X<3>> a; // valid? invalid?
  ```
- most vexing parse:

  ```
      std::istream_iterator<int> first(std::cin); // declares a variable
      std::istream_iterator<int> last();          // declares a function
  ```

Etc.

---

#### Meanings of Qualification

(original response)

The first is 'const/volatile' qualification

A variable/function/parameter declaration includes a type. This type can be 'const' or 'volatile' qualified to modify the semantics of the type.

The second is namespace qualification

C++ can group names into namespaces, to avoid clashes. The *unqalified name* is enough to refer to identifiers declared in the current or visible namespaces:

```
namespace ns1
{
    struct X {};
    X f();
}

using namespace ns1;
X f2();
```

However to

- refer to names outside the current/visible namespace(s)
- disambiguate conflicting visible declarations in multiple namespaces

you'll have to use what's known as the 'qualified' name:

```
struct X {} ;
namespace ns2
{
    struct X {};
    ns2::X f();
    ns1::X g();
}

X h(); // uses ::X

using namespace ns2;

::X i();    // disambiguate
ns2::X i();
```